# ARP responses not arriving to virtual interface in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, arp

I created virtual interface in Linux from command line, and asked for an IP address from the router with the following commands:

```
ip link add link enp0s3 my-iface type macvlan 
ifconfig my-iface up 
dhclient -v my-iface
```

After receiving IP successfully, I am trying to send ping from the virtual interface to other components in the network, and I get "Destination Host Unreachable". The reason is that there is no ARP resolving. ARP is sent to know the MAC of the requested pinged IP, response arrives to the enp interface, but not transferred from enp to my virtual interface.

I guess it's a routing issue, but I hoped that this will be solved due to the linking command when creating the interface.

How can I solve it? Is something wrong with the creation of the interface?